# Sending formGroup to child component and populate form Angular

Tags: angular

app.component.html

```
<h1 class="text-center">Product Review System- Add Product Module</h1>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly mt-5">
  <form [formGroup]="product" class="w-50" name="add-product" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="product-id">Product Id:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="product-id" type="text" formControlName="id"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="product-name">Product Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="product-id" type="text" formControlName="name"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="product-image">Add Image:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="product-image" type="file" formControlName="productImage" accept="image/*"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
  <label for="feature">Add Features:</label>
  <app-feature *ngFor="let feature of features"></app-feature>
  <p class="text-center p-2"><a class="add-feature" href="#" (click)="addFeature()">Add another feature</a></p>
  </div>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Add Product" />
  </form>
</div>
```

feature.component.html

```
    <input class="form-control m-2" type="text" />
```

app.component.ts

```
    export class AppComponent {
      product = this.fb.group({
        id: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(11)]],
        name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(21)]],
        productImage: [null, [Validators.required]],
        features: ""
      });
      features: Array<FeatureComponent> = [new FeatureComponent()];
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
      }
      onSubmit(): void{
        alert(this.product.value);
        console.log(this.product.value);
      }
      addFeature(): void{
        this.features.push(new FeatureComponent());
      }
    }
```

feature.component.ts

```
export class FeatureComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() { }
ngOnInit(): void {
  }}
```

> On add feature click I have create a input for a feature now I want to
> populate form data with all the features user enters.

[image: Form]

Answer (score 0):

Using FormArray we can achieve the scenario.

Consider the features as FormArray.

app.component.ts.

```
get featureFormArray() {
    return this.fearureForm.get('fearures') as FormArray
}

this.fb.group({
 id: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(11)]],
 name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(21)]],
 productImage: [null, [Validators.required]],
 features: this.fb.array([this.addFeature()])
});

addFeature() {
   return this.fb.group({ input: '' })
}
```

Loop the feature form array controls in app.component.html

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let featureFormCtrl of featureFormArray.controls">
    <app-feature [group]="featureFormCtrl"></app-feature>
</div>
```

In feature component accept the feature form group as Input property

feature.component.ts

```
@Input() group: FormGroup
```

feature.component.html

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="group">
    <input formControlName="input" class="form-control m-2" type="text" />
</ng-container>
```

On add feature click call in app.component.html

```
addFeatureClick() {
    this.featureFormArray.push(this.addFeature())
}
```

The form value be as below

```
{
      id: "",
      name: "",
      productImage: "",
      features: [{input: ''}, {input: ''}]
 }
```